# Best way to separate live and test environemnts in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I want to provide test and live environment in AWS.
My environment contains AWS services like Lambda, API-Gateway etc. for testing purposes and live usage.

What is the best way to separate test and live environments in AWS?

Is it a good idea to create a organization with a master account and
use this master account for live environment, then create another account
which belongs to the same organization and use it for test environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many paradigms with trade-offs - mostly dealing with your tolerance for administrative overhead and isolation.

### Two Accounts with Organizations

As you mention, there is the pattern of Master Organization Account and Testing Account. There are some lines of thinking suggesting that it's an unnecessary risk to put your production, customer-facing assets in your master billing account, because a compromise within that account compromises your whole organization. That said, this is still a very common pattern.

### Three+ Accounts with Organizations

You can use your Master accounts to house your federation and access to all of your other accounts and nothing else. This allows you to apply service control policies on your production account to better protect it and limit the scope of a compromise. If you want to dive down the rabbit hole, you can put your identity federation work in its own account, but before you accept this level (or more) of complexity, make sure it's meeting a business need or mitigating a risk commensurate with the business cost.

### Separation with IAM

You can operate test and live environments within a single account, but it would probably not be advisable due to the administrative overhead. If you create a set of IAM policies/roles and prefix their names with TEST, and use them with policies that only allow permissions on other resources with TEST at the beginning of their name (i.e. they could only create resources that begin with TEST and could only modify resources that begin with TEST). Then repeat the process for LIVE. To separate data, you could use LIVE and TEST KMS keys with a policy only granting permissions to roles in the same environment. If you use IAM Users you can give them `sts:assumeRole` permission on whichever TEST or LIVE roles they needed, and they could use the switch role feature in the console or the `sts assume-role` command on the cli or api to operate either one of the environments. An example policy for interacting with lambda might look like this:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:ListLayerVersions",
                "lambda:ListLayers",
                "lambda:GetAccountSettings",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TestOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:337676836613:layer:TEST*:*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:337676836613:event-source-mapping:TEST*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:337676836613:function:TEST*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:337676836613:layer:TEST*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This wouldn't prevent either environments from being able to run `list*` api calls and see the presence and/or names of resource from the other environment, but resources from one environment wouldn't be able to perform `describe*` api calls to see any information/metadata about resources in the other environment, and would not be able to instantiate new resources in the other environment, and would not be able to modify resources in the other environment. With KMS thoroughly locking down data, you wouldn't even be able to copy data between environments without using an intermediary. However, this wouldn't work if you wanted to have different account-wide settings/defaults for services (like VPC Trunking in ECS), because they are account-wide and would affect all of your environments.

However, this would require some well crafted policies, and unless you're very familiar with IAM, using AWS Organizations is an easier way. The advantage of this way is it is very explicit about separations between environments. Since AWS API calls can traverse accounts, it becomes possible for resources in one account to start using resources in others (assuming roles, sharing S3 buckets, sharing KMS CMKs, etc.). A multi-account strategy might overlook this and as the environments become more connected over time, unwanted leaks between accounts become possible.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I prefer the 'Two Accounts with Organizations' paradigm. Because of cost and complexity balance as you said and the other one is definitely a administrative overhead.

Answer (score 1):

There are [different project and environment separation strategies for AWS](https://winterwindsoftware.com/managing-separate-projects-in-aws/), that you can use to achieve your goal. Besides the already described "Separation by IAM" approach you can also consider trying out [Separation by Account](https://winterwindsoftware.com/managing-separate-projects-in-aws/#approach-3--separation-by-aws-account). This could result in an account hierarchy that is similar to following figure from [this AWS answer](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-multi-account-billing-strategy/?nc1=h_ls).

[image: Project-oriented account hierarchy]

### How to achieve separation by account

First you need to create an AWS Organization with your master account that will operate as your project account. Then you add to your organization either existing AWS accounts by inviting them or you create new ones with help of AWS Organizations (in this case be aware of [possible pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59751391/5305936)). After you've done creating and organizing accounts you will automatically get a clean sandbox environment for each account, where no resource collision could happen.

### Your benefits

- you don't need to take care about correct prefixes or suffixes for your resources
- with consolidated billing you will get clear overview about costs of each resource stack and each account
- you don't need a credit card for each account if you create them from AWS Organizations interface

Answer (score 0):

AWS elasticbean service can be leveraged to achieve this functionality.

Below is snippet:
Blue/green deployments require that your environment runs independently of your production database, if your application uses one. Example, If your environment has an Amazon RDS DB instance attached to it, the data will not transfer over to your second environment, and will be lost if you terminate the original environment.

More details, please refer below link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk

Hope this helps to get started.

Comment: Thank you first of all. And sorry I think my question was not clear I update it. I meant aws whole services for test and for live and not a specific service or application. 

For example in region Paris I have my Lambdas, API-Gateways etc. for live usage and in the region London Lambdas and other services for my test usage. But I think to seperate in regions is not good because the risk that you quickly miss in which region you are is higher. So I thougt its better to have different accounts.